# Why am I unable to specify height and width for images on my asp.net website? (html output included)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, performance

Whenever I run a speed test on Google or [GMetrix](http://gtmetrix.com), they always give me an F because they say my image sizes aren't specified, so more http requests are required.  But on my asp.net (vb) website, the links they specify are linkbuttons and look like this **using CssClass**:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image9" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/flagpt.png" 
CssClass="flagbutton" tooltip="Veja este site em portuguÃªs" 
title="Veja este site em portuguÃªs"/>
```

This results in this **html output** (using CssClass) but still doesn't have img dimensions:

```
<img id="Image9" title="Veja este site em portuguÃªs" 
 class="flagbutton" title="Veja este site em portuguÃªs" 
 src="images/flagpt.png" />
```

But if I just put **height="15" width="26"** like this, it still **doesn't** work:

```
  <asp:Image ID="Image7" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/flagde.png" 
  height="15" width="26" tooltip="View this website in Deutsch" 
  title="View this website in Deutsch"/>
```

This results in this **html output**, but speed tests don't detect img dimensions:

```
<img id="Image7" title="View this website in Deutsch" 
   title="View this website in Deutsch" 
   src="images/flagde.png" style="height:15px;width:26px;" />
```

The speed tests still suggest I'm not specifying my dimensions.  Any suggestions to help me with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you see in the html output?

Comment: Hi @Amiram. When I right-click and view page source, if I specify dimensions by manually typing in height="15" width="26", it looks like this: <a id="btnSelectFrench" class="flagbutton" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$btnSelectFrench&#39;,&#39;&#39;)"><img id="Image6" title="Voir ce site en franÃ§ais" title="Voir ce site en franÃ§ais" src="images/flagfr.png" style="height:15px;width:26px;" />

Comment: If I use the CssClass="flagbutton" as specified in my stylesheet, and view the page source, it looks empty, like nothing's there:       <a id="btnSelectDutch" class="flagbutton" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$btnSelectDutch&#39;,&#39;&#39;)"><img id="Image1" title="Bekijk deze website in het Nederlands" class="flagbutton" title="Bekijk deze website 
      in het Nederlands" src="images/flagnl.png" />  .............. thank you for taking the time to read my question!  I appreciate it!

Comment: Please add this to your question

Comment: Thank you Amiram.  I edited the question and narrowed the scope so there's not as much clutter; hopefully it's more clear now!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, not specifying image dimensions won't result in extra HTTP requests. It might result in the browser having to re-flow your document once the image is downloaded, but that's a different issue.

Secondly, you *have* specified your image dimensions. It's right there in the output:

```
style="height:15px;width:26px;"
```

Specifying the `width` and `height` attributes as well should not be necessary.

If you really want to force the output to include the `width` and `height` attributes, you'll either need to use a custom control or a control adapter. Something like this should do the trick:

```
public class ImageDimensionsAdapter : WebControlAdapter
{
   protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   {
      var image = Control as Image;
      if (image != null)
      {
         Unit size = image.Width;
         if (!size.IsEmpty && size.Type == UnitType.Pixel)
         {
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Width, size.Value.ToString("###0"));
         }

         size = image.Height;
         if (!size.IsEmpty && size.Type == UnitType.Pixel)
         {
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Height, size.Value.ToString("###0"));
         }
      }

      base.Render(writer);
   }
}
```

To apply it, add a `.browser` file in your `App_Browsers` directory containing the following:

```
<browsers>
   <browser refID="Default">
      <controlAdapters>
         <adapter
            controlType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image"
            adapterType="ImageDimensionsAdapter"
         />
      </controlAdapters>
   </browser>
</browsers>
```

Comment: Looks like this is a known bug in PageSpeed, reported in March 2011: http://code.google.com/p/page-speed/issues/detail?id=469